# React JS Inheritance get data

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

Hi I am developing an application with React JS.
I have a problem.

TopBottomCard.js

```
export default class TopBottomCard extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)

}

 getEnlem(){
    return this.props.enlem
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
    example</div>
   )}
```

Map.js

```
import TopBottomCard from './TopBottomCard'

export default class Map extends TopBottomCard {
constructor(){
    super(this)
}


render() {
    const top = new TopBottomCard()
    const url = 'https://www.example.com/map.html?'+top.getEnlem+''
    console.log(url);

    return (
        <div style={{height:'100vh'}}>

        </div>
    )
}
  }
```

When I go to the localhost: 3000 / map page I get an output like this.

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/map.html?function () { [native code] }
```

When I change the "url" variable on the Map.js page as follows, it gives an error.

```
 const url = 'https://www.example.com/map.html?'+top.getEnlem()+''
```

Error code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'enlem' of undefined
How do I solve this?

Comment: Why are you creating a react component with `new MyComponent(props)` and not `<MyComponent prop={val} />` and why are you trying to get a prop value from TopBottomCard using a non public function that returns a prop value you didn't pass in the constructor? Also; I don't think you can create react components in this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you create 'Map' class, make sure the constructor get the props and pass them to the parent, using super(this) will not do the trick.
Also make sure you actually send props to the class you instantiate so it will not be undefined.

```
class TopBottomCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    getEnlem(){
        return this.props.enlem
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>example</div>
        )
    }
}

class Map extends TopBottomCard {
    constructor(props) { // get the props in this constructor as well
        super(props) // and pass them to the parent constructor
    }

    render() {
        const top = new TopBottomCard({}) // you need to send props so it will not be undefined in the component
        const url = 'https://www.example.com/map.html?' + top.getEnlem() + ''  
        return (
            <div style={{height:'100vh'}}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```